# Source Code Pro font issue in JetBrains editors

Tags: fonts, ruby

I'm having trouble with Source Code Pro font for few years now on all JetBrains IDE's.

I have installed [Source Code Pro](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-code-pro). When I set the font:
[image]

I have these weird bugs, mainly in Ruby:
[image: ...]

But this bug goes away, if I use comment symbol twice:
[image]

I have no idea what could be causing this.

Here's another example of this problem:
[image]

From all the fonts I used, this is my absolutely favorite, but this bug is extremely annoying.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this, without using another font?

Note that this only happens with semibold version. Regular version doesn't have this bug..

Comment: I assume you have reported the issue to JetBrains?